# SQL PIVOT Rows Into Matrix With Empty Column Results

Tags: sql, matrix, pivot, unpivot, kendo-dataviz

I was needing to get my data into a format that works smoothly for kendo grid ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/tinkerer/9VZdS/)). This example is actually a hack to try to color individual chart bars which isn't available by default. If you format your data correctly you can stack the bars in groups and you are able to color each group.

**My data needed to be structured like this with the 1st column names as column headers**

```
names               CompletedAllCourses   HasExpiredCourses   HasNotTakenCourses  HasDueCourses
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CompletedAllCourses   12                  NULL                NULL                 NULL
HasDueCourses         NULL                NULL                NULL                 4
HasExpiredCourses     NULL                8                   NULL                 NULL
HasNotTakenCourses    NULL                NULL                24                   NULL
```

**This is what I had to start with GroupedStats Table**

```
CompletedAllCourses     12
HasDueCourses           4
HasExpiredCourses       8
HasNotTakenCourses      24
```

I tried the following query from an example I found online.

```
SELECT * FROM  GroupedStats
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(cnt) FOR cat IN (CompletedAllCourses, 
          HasExpiredCourses, HasNotTakenCourses, HasDueCourses)
) p
```

**This was the result.**

```
CompletedAllCourses HasExpiredCourses HasNotTakenCourses HasDueCourses
------------------- ----------------- ------------------ -------------
12                  8                 24                 4
```

I figured out one way and posted it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the required result but it requires hardcoded literals in `CASE`:

```
  SELECT cat,
  CASE cat WHEN 'CompletedAllCourses' THEN CompletedAllCourses ELSE NULL END AS CompletedAllCourses,
  CASE cat WHEN 'HasExpiredCourses' THEN HasExpiredCourses ELSE NULL END AS HasExpiredCourses,
  CASE cat WHEN 'HasNotTakenCourses' THEN HasNotTakenCourses ELSE NULL END AS HasNotTakenCourses,
  CASE cat WHEN 'HasDueCourses' THEN HasDueCourses ELSE NULL END AS HasDueCourses
  FROM GroupedStats
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT * FROM  GroupedStats
    PIVOT 
    (
      MAX(cnt) FOR cat IN (CompletedAllCourses, 
            HasExpiredCourses, HasNotTakenCourses, HasDueCourses)
    ) p
  ) X
  ON 1 = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d57aa/5)

Answer (score 0):

**PIVOT Example to save the day**

I moved this part of this post into the answer because it was ultimately what worked for me.

**Need another column to fix things up or things collapse into one result.**

```
select * from 
(select cat as names, cnt, cat FROM GroupedStats) x
PIVOT 
(
MAX(cnt) FOR cat IN (CompletedAllCourses, HasExpiredCourses, 
        HasNotTakenCourses, HasDueCourses)
) p
```

[sql fiddle] (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b706/3)

**And I get the format I wanted PROBLEM SOLVED! Please comment if you can add to the explanation.**

```
names                 CompletedAllCourses HasExpiredCourses HasNotTakenCourses HasDueCourses
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CompletedAllCourses    12                 NULL              NULL                 NULL
HasDueCourses          NULL               NULL              NULL                 4
HasExpiredCourses      NULL               8                 NULL                 NULL
HasNotTakenCourses     NULL               NULL              24                   NULL
```